# Example project for android-screenshot-library

Tags: android, eclipse, screenshot, setup-project

I'm trying to make a simple eclipse project that only takes one screenshot using the android-screenshot-library. The thing is that the documentation is very very poor and I'm having a hard time understanding how to set up this very very simple project.

Anyone knowing about some example project in the web? or useful tutorial (step-by-step kind of thing).

Answer (score 0):

**Have look at this.**

[Android Screen Shot Library](https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/)

Answer (score -1):

Follow the tutorial here.  It isn't about pictures and cameras, but it's simple enough to get you started.  Then post code of what you have tried and ask and more pointed question:     http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html